# Render events in full calendar on drop down's change event

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I have 1 drop down list for select status of the task and one button , so I basically want to load the events according to the status(new,In progress,completed)
I have implemented it , it fetches all the events perfectly but not rendered in the full calendar...
When first i click on full calendar , it will show me all the events.. for that i had given  events:'GetAllEvents' and it works fine but when i change the  values from drop down , It is not rendering

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.status, db.getStatus(), "---Select---", new { id = "taskstatus", multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })   
 </div>

  $('#taskstatus').multiselect({  
                 nonSelectedText: '- - -Select Status- - -',    
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    maxHeight: 400,
                    dropUp: true,
                    buttonWidth: 180,
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    enableHTML: true,
                    buttonClass: 'btn small btn-primary',
                    templates: {
                    button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="multiselect-selected-text"></span> &nbsp;<b class="fa fa-caret-down"></b></button>',
                    ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"></ul>',
                    filter: '<li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><input class="form-control multiselect-search" type="text"></div></li>',
                    filterClearBtn: '<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-white btn-grey multiselect-clear-filter" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times-circle red2"></i></button></span>',
                    li: '<li><a tabindex="0"><label></label></a></li>',
                    divider: '<li class="multiselect-item divider"></li>',
                    liGroup: '<li class="multiselect-item multiselect-group"><label></label></li>' }

           });    

     $('#taskstatus').change( function(){
            debugger;
            var events = 'GetProjectsBack';

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', events);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);         
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
        }).change();
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProjectsBack(string start, string end,GetDataToCalendarModel model)
    {
        var rows = (dynamic)null;
        var len_Status_Id  = 1;
        if (len_Status_Id != 0)
        {

            string date1 = startdate;
            string date2 = enddate;
            var ApptListForDate = LoadSelectedTasks(date1, date2, model);
            var eventList = from e in ApptListForDate
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.Task_Run_Id,
                                status = e.status,
                                project_name = e.Project_Name,
                                title = e.Task_Name,
                                task_id = e.Task_Id,
                                project_id = e.Project_Id,
                                comment = e.comment1,
                                start = e.start_time,
                                end = e.end_time,
                                allDay = false,
                                username = e.UserName,

                                className = "label-important",
                            };
            rows = eventList.ToArray();


          }

        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);




    }

    public static List<Task_runsModel> LoadSelectedTasks(string start, string end,GetDataToCalendarModel calmodel)
    {
        string status = null;
        var len_Status_Id = 1;
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
       List<Task_runsModel> result = new List<Task_runsModel>();
       for(int j=0;j<len_Status_Id;j++)
       {


               status = "Completed";


            var sql = "SELECT * from task_runs where active = 1 AND  dead = 0 ANd status= '" + status + "' ";

            var data = Database.Open("DefaultConnection").Query(sql);


            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Task_runsModel model = new Task_runsModel();
                model.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(item.UserId);
                model.Task_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Task_Id);
                model.Task_Run_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Task_Run_Id);
                model.Task_Name = (from i in db.ProjectTaskModels
                                   where i.Task_Id == model.Task_Id
                                   select i.Task_Name).FirstOrDefault();
                model.Project_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Project_Id);
                model.Project_Name = (from i in db.ProjectMasterModels
                                      where i.Project_Id == model.Project_Id
                                      select i.Project_Name).FirstOrDefault();
                model.status = item.status.ToString();

                model.start_time = (item.start_time).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                model.end_time = (item.end_time).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                model.comment1 = item.comment1.ToString();
                model.UserName = (from i in db.UserProfiles
                                  where i.UserId == model.UserId
                                  select i.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

                result.Add(model);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: can anyone please help me out?

Comment: can you show how the fullCalendar is configured, please, including the ajax call? AFAIK you shouldn't need to remove and re-add the event source for this, running refetch events should be sufficient, as long as it's wired up to check the value of the "taskStatus" field and send that. Also, do you get any browser console errors when you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved , i have just added one line   $('.fc-event').remove(); , so it will remove the previously loaded calendar events and new events according to the drop down will be displayed

```
$('#taskstatus').change( function(){
            debugger;

           var myevents = 'GetProjectsBack';
           $('.fc-event').remove();
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources'); 
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', myevents);

        }).change();
```

Comment: pretty sure this is unnecessary, there should be a neater solution. You shouldn't have to manipulate the fullCalendar elements directly - that's the whole point of the events API. Something else is going wrong I would suspect. But at least you got it working, after a fashion.

Comment: If you have a better solution then please let me know because i also know that , this solution is not neater ,Thanks

Comment: I can't unless you share your fullCalendar setup code, because you may be doing something which is affecting the normal behaviour. As I mentioned above though, just running "refetchEvents" ought to be sufficient to refresh the events, but it depends on how you've got everything else wired up.